# Ошибка в командной строке — «NameError: name 'extension' is not defined. Did you mean: 'Exception'?»

Tags: python, веб-программирование, discord

Есть вот такой у меня код, это основной файл бота. Я решил сделать коги, что показалось мне отличным решением всех моих проблем, связанных с многострочностью строк в коде бота. И зачастую я в нём теряюсь. Но при запуске основного файла main.py (я использую .bat файл для запуска кода на своём компьютере) в командной строке я получаю ошибку:

```
C:\Users\user 2\Downloads\Папки\BOT DISCORD\BLACK RUSSIA BONUS>py main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user 2\Downloads\Папки\BOT DISCORD\BLACK RUSSIA BONUS\main.py", line 93, in <module>
    bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension[:-3]}")
                               ^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'extension' is not defined. Did you mean: 'Exception'?
```

Код основного файла — main.py:

```
async def load(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == 737468084763230242:
        bot.load_extension("cogs.logs.py")
        bot.load_extension("cogs.moderation_commands")
        await ctx.send(f"Cogs были успешно загружены на сервер бота. Вызвал команду: {ctx.author.mention}")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'Не удалось загрузить Cogs. Вы — не разработчик бота. Вызвал команду: {ctx.author.mention}')    

@bot.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == 737468084763230242:
        bot.unload_extension("cogs.logs.py")
        bot.unload_extension("cogs.moderation_commands")
        await ctx.send(f"Cogs были успешно выгружены с сервера бота. Вызвал команду: {ctx.author.mention}")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'Не удалось выгрузить Cogs с сервера бота. Вы — не разработчик бота.')      


@bot.command()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == 737468084763230242:
        bot.unload_extension("cogs.moderation_commands")
        bot.unload_extension("cogs.logs.py")
        bot.load_extension("cogs.logs.py")
        bot.load_extension("cogs.moderation_commands")
        await ctx.send(f"Cogs были успешно перезагружены. Вызвал команду: {ctx.author.mention}")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'Не удалось перезагрузить Cogs. Вы — не разработчик бота.')

for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension[:-3]}")
```

Comment: Может этот `for` должен быть внутри функции `reload`? Тогда ему не хватает отступов.

Comment: А в каком месте, вне функций, у Вас определена переменная `extension`? И думаю, @CrazyElf прав, по поводу того, что у Вас не хватает отступов перед циклом, поскольку в Вашем варианте он находится вне функции для которой определена переменная `extension`

Comment: @Namerek `extension` есть только в парааметрах async def, уточните, пожалуйста как я могу в этом коде создать переменную `extension` и передать её в bot.load_extension? ни разу не видел гайда на видеохостингах / топиках на форумах как это сделать, вы очень поможете

Comment: Ну то есть всё-таки цикл у вас может быть и вне функций, он сам по себе выполняется? Лучше покажите весь код бота. И откуда вы взяли такую структуру бота - с параметром `extension` у команд и вот этой строкой `f"cogs.{extension[:-3]}"`?

Comment: Видеоуроки при непонимании основ, в большинстве своем - зло в чистом виде. Читайте документацию.

Comment: @Namerek не соглсен. документацию тоже нужно понимать. лично я благодаря видеоурокам достаточно много выучил и сейчас спокойно пишу бота.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас никуда не определяется `extension`. Я предполагаю чей вы смотрели видео-урок. Вам необходимо сделать `cogs.extension`. Таким образом по названию файла (без `.py`) вы можете перезагрузить определенный `cog`.

```
bot.reload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
```

И ещё хотелось отметить, что `cog` можно перезагрузить одной строкой используя `reload`.

```
@bot.command() 
async def reload(ctx, extension): 
    if ctx.author.id == 737468084763230242: 
        bot.reload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        await ctx.send(f"Cog были успешно перезагружены. Вызвал команду: {ctx.author.mention}")
    else: 
        await ctx.send(f'Не удалось перезагрузить Cogs. Вы — не разработчик бота.')
```

Во-вторых, ошибка которая у Вас возникает, заключается в строке загрузки самих когов. Вы допустили ошибку в `(f"cogs.{extension[:-3]}")`. Исправьте `extension` на **`filename`**.

```
for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"): 
    if filename.endswith(".py"): 
        bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
```